# categoryAxis Labels for the stacked column on a Kendo jQuery Barchart

Tags: kendo-ui, bar-chart

I have a simple data structure that I am pushing into a Kendo UI Barchart and stacking associated rows via a common grouped field in Kendo UI jQuery.

The Barchart is displayed as intended, but the ONLY customization I am unable to achieve is to show the "stacked" category labels which show what the elements have been grouped into, "Democrat" and "Republican" in the below sample.

Sample code:

```
    function createChart() {
        $("#stackie").kendoChart({
            seriesDefaults: {
                type: "bar",
                     stack: {
                            type: true
                        },
                labels: {
                visible: true,
                background: "transparent",
                position: "center",
                template: "${series.name} ${value}"
                }
            },
         series: [
            {"stack": "Democrat",  name: "New York",  data: [854]}, 
            {"stack": "Democrat",name: "Boston",  data: [190]},
            {"stack": "Republican",name: "Texas",  data: [190]},
            {"stack": "Democrat",name: "Philadelphia",  data: [390]},
            {"stack": "Democrat",name: "Atlanta",  data: [390]},
            {"stack": "Republican",name: "Florida",  data: [390]},
            {"stack": "Republican",name: "Alabama",  data: [390]},
            {"stack": "Republican",name: "Detroit",  data: [390]}
            ],
            valueAxis: {
                labels: {
                    template: "#= kendo.format('{0:N0}', value) #"
                },
                line: {
                    visible: false
                }
            },
            categoryAxis: {
               field: "stack",
               visible: true
            },
            legend: {
              position: "none"
            }
        });
    }
```

Whatever options I set for the "categoryaxis" seem to be ignored and I end up with a stacked barchart with no category grouping labels as below:

[image]
There doesnt seem to be an easy/intuitive way to get at the underlying "stacked" data. I would also want to show the aggregated totals for each "stack" too.

Any ideas? Thanks